# How do I change to the directory I just moved that file to?

Tags: linux, unix, bash, shell, directory

So lets assume I've just done:

```
mv ./myfile /to/some/other/place/
```

And I now decide I want to follow the file, and go into that directory.

Whilst I could head for the mouse, select the text, type 'cd ', then right-click to paste - I'd prefer a faster keyboard-based directory.

So, what's the best way to do that?
(In general, and if different, Centos+Bash specifically)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you type "!$" it will print the last argument of the previous line.  Which will be the directory you moved the file into.

Comment: Best thing I've learned all day.

Comment: Rory's cd $_ is Posix, so it will work on ksh and bourne shell as well as bash.

Comment: "cd $_" doesn't work in csh or tcsh, but it does work in zsh.  csh and tcsh support !$, though.

Just for the record.

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
cd !$
```

Comment: Thanks - this works, but thepocketwade gave a fuller answer so have accepted his one.

Answer (score 4):

Try "cd" and then "[Alt] + ." (can be used repeatedly)
It will scroll all your previous commands last parameter. So it will look like:

```
mv ./myfile /to/some/other/place/
cd <Alt>+.
```

Comment: Thanks, also helpful since sometimes I might not want the immediately preceding command.

Comment: Here's another useful bash trick for you: Using Ctrl+r will let you quickly search your history by typing in a partial command. Can also be used repeatedly to scroll back to older parts of your history

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Esc</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> (Escape followed by Period) Gives you the last argument of the previous command, it is a [readline](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) shortcut.  You can type it many times to cycle through the last arguments of previous commands.  Readline is a command line entry library that is used by many shells (such as bash, same maintainer), irc clients, etc.

This is probably my favorite keyboard shortcut (followed by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> for start of line and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>e</kbd> for end of line), give it a try ;-)

Update: Oh, katriel posted <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>.</kbd> , this is the same thing, just different a key (<kbd>Alt</kbd> instead of <kbd>Esc</kbd>)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `$_` as the last argument of the last command line